# What LEGO set do these numbered bags of pieces come from?

Tags: set-identification

I found these bags in the attic any idea what LEGO set they belong to?

[image: Bags 1, 3 and 5]

They are numbered 1, 3 and 5, but I don't know if they all came from the same set or not.

Comment: Hello Daron. The link you provided goes to your personal inbox, which nobody but you can see. Can you try to upload them differently? Without pictures we cannot help you. The codes you posted are production codes, which indicate this was from (a) set(s) that were produced only recently (week 20 of 2019) which makes me curious how you found them “in the attic” as they cannot have been there long ...

Comment: The codes on the bags are for the bags themselves, rather than the sets.

Comment: I'll admit that I'm struggling to find a set that contains both a [Medium Lilac 6X6 Bow](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-6022021) and the [Bright Yellow Right Plate 3X8 W/Angle](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-4247642)

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid exactly those were my starting points as well. And the lack of any coherent topic or aesthetic.

Comment: Could be these are bags from a new set that are not yet in the bricklink or brickset system. But more likely this is a hoax. Numbered bags like these have only been used like last 8 years, why would they be "in the attic" ? Why are they so sparsely and randomly filled ?

Comment: It's possible these were given out as collections from a Fast Food stores.
Mcs, BK or KFC, for example.

Comment: Bag #1 has two pieces already connected together, too.

Comment: What does the QR code on the bag scan to? I tried to scan from the provided image and it didn't work, so perhaps the image resolution is too low.

Comment: Very long shot, but is it possible that these are components of the playing field for a [FIRST LEGO League](https://www.firstinspires.org/robotics/fll) challenge?

Comment: @Eilon The problem with the two QR codes is not the resolution. The top one is shot on black background, meaning some information is lost. The fact that the QR code itself is really low-resolution means that it has little to no redundancy, making it unscannable. The bottom one is slightly warped, meaning that the timing information can't be read anymore. I would have to recreate the QR code from scratch.

Comment: @Eilon Alright, I [recreated the bottom QR code in Paint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgsJY.png) and when scanned, it translates to `6172092`

Comment: The QR codes on lego building bags indeed translate to 7 digit numbers, but there is to my knowledge no database available to the public that keeps track of these numbers.

Answer (score 17):

These bags don't seem to belong to any specific LEGO set.

First, they are filled very sparsely. Normally LEGO bags are filled with more elements than that depicted here.

Secondly, in bag #3 we clearly see [a Plate 6X6 W. Bow in medium lilac](https://brickset.com/parts/6022021):

[image: image of Plate 6X6 W. Bow in medium lilac]

And a [Right Plate 3X8 W/Angle in bright yellow](https://brickset.com/parts/4247642/right-plate-3x8-w-angle):

[image: image of Right Plate 3X8 W/Angle in bright yellow]

But these two parts have never been sold in the same set. [These contain the lilac plate](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-6022021), and [these the yellow plate](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-4247642).

So the only remaining possibilities are, in order of descending probability:

1. The bags have been opened and the contents changed (possibly resealed later)
2. These are not genuine LEGO products (but the bags do have "The LEGO Group" printed on them)
3. Someone at a LEGO factory has made a grave mistake

Comment: Option 4 - Brickset is incomplete.

Comment: Sound like a legit answer

Comment: @Moo Could be, but highly improbable, as Brickset takes its data from Bricklink, whose maintainers had vested monetary interest in keeping the content correct, current and complete. Now, with the acquisition by TLG there is absolutely nothing that could prevent the Bricklink and thus the Brickset databases being complete.

Answer (score 11):

The dark purple plate pulls up only three sets, but these brick combinations don't match a set from those three.  Hmmm... If the bags are sealed then they might have been a custom *LEGO* "*Pick-a-Brick*" order.

LEGO has two versions of the LEGO Pick-A-Brick service.  One is inside a brick and mortar store, the other is selected on line.

If a customer's online order exceeds a certain threshold, (can't remember, something like 200 bricks), then the order is sent to the LEGO main distribution factory in Denmark, which adds three or so weeks to get your bricks, but I think they seal/ship them in these bags.

Comment: Do you know if there's any other online examples of sealed bags for larger orders?

Comment: I've found a couple of examples of [other sealed](https://www.flickr.com/photos/jeroen_k/5978936386/) or [ziplock'ed](https://www.flickr.com/photos/zalbaar/7541746458/) bags, so in principle this is sound - just seems extreme that these don't have the order details and are so sparsely packed.